# Should an accepted answer supply a "tag point"?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, tags, profile-page

I don't know if they have a name, but the "points" which show up next to tag on your stats page (and on the leaderboard in the tag stats page) don't seem to be affected by accepted answers.

For example, if I provide an answer, and receive no upvotes for it, but it is accepted as the answer, don't you think it should add a point to your tag stat?

An example: if you look at the [top users page for XNA](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xna/topusers), there are two columns. One is the total number of answers provided. The other is "total score", which is the total number of upvotes which you have received. My score would be higher (even if slightly so) if accepted answers were used in that "total score" because there have been a few cases where my answer is [accepted, but no upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A5416%20%5Bxna%5D%20score%3A0..0%20isaccepted%3Ayes&searchOn=3) were received.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think accepted answers should contribute to your tag score.  Having an accepted answer only means the OP thinks your answer is correct, and the OP has a vested interest in getting an answer that works for him/her.  What truly counts, IMO, is the people who do not have a vested interest in the outcome of the question, the people who simply think the answer is clear, concise, and correct.

In other words, I say leave it as it is.

Comment: ...although it would be neat to see that information, too.

Comment: Agreed, I'd love to see in one place a tally of the number of accepted answers I've given, the total number of upvotes and downvotes received in questions and answers (both CW and non) etc... this is most likely going to happen with greasemonkey scripts using API calls though.

Comment: But for now, you'll have to use search for such stats: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A132636+hasaccepted%3A1 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A132636+isaccepted%3A1 @eth

Comment: But what if the OP does't have the rep to upvote you, and (s)he would otherwise have upvoted. They can only accept. I those cases where OP does't have the rep to upvote, the accept should count as an upvote for tally. I might be hard to implement though.

Comment: The argument is based on an assumption that people upvote answers just for being "clear, concise, and correct". I'm challenging its validity. This assumption draws a picture of a "average user" as someone who idly browses through questions, voting on things based on some standard. This is hardly the dominant usage pattern of SO 'cuz active users are a minority. More likely, an "average user" is someone who has a specific problem and goes to SO for a solution, voting on whatever was (un)helpful for them -- making their votes just as subjective and personal as the acceptance mark was.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, my concern is that people on SO usually have an area of expertise, tag counts and badges reflect that. We are saying, yes you helped someone with exactly what they needed, yet it's not good enough to count for the tags.

I get that if the user marks an answer correct, they "should" up-vote it, but why make that complex? I see this all the time with new users.

Some argue that marking an answer correct has nothing to do with up-voting. I disagree, receiving a random anonymous up-vote from someone shouldn't have more tag value than the OP's correctly marked answer.

My suggestion:

+15 for a correct answer, with 10 for the upvote and 5 for it being correct, and not allow any further upvoting by the OP(ie: +15, then +10 for one upvote).

Answer (score -1):

I do suggest that while we have the current scenario, it would be good if we could see the number of accepted answers per Tag.