# Accepted answers v. tag badge counts

Tags: feature-request

Dupe of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46795/why-are-accepted-answers-not-included-in-the-tag-badge-calculation) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71328/tag-badges-for-accepted-answers).

If only a dozen people see the question, none of them upvote, but it's accepted, it seems to me it should count towards a tag badge.

The low-volume tags don't provide the same level of "compensation" as the popular ones, and there's no reputation weighting based on how many people view (or know) stuff.

I know it's a personal choice to toil silently and get the occasional upvote and acceptance, but it seems like there should be some way of recognizing the obscure laborer besides the Unsung Hero.

Am I missing something that goes along with participating in low-volume, largely-un-upvoted tags, other than the visceral thrill of answering a question only a tiny fraction of the world's population will ever see?

Comment: Post a world class answer behind a good question (if necessary, nicely edited and tidied up with a good Googleable title) and you'll slowly but surely get enough votes. A to-the-point answer of one sentence or two is not worth voting. A in depth explanation with some solid code examples is (so that the answer is also understandable for the curious). At least, that's my experience in the niche tags.

Answer (score 7):

An accept is not the same as an upvote.  It's worth more rep in order to herd us toward answering the asker's question rather than just pandering to the community for votes.  (Those green check marks are supposed to say "the site solved my problem".)  But in terms of actual *quality*, an accept doesn't carry anywhere near the same weight as an upvote.  Nor should it.  We can often presume that askers don't really know whether the answer is *actually any good* -- if they did, they generally wouldn't be asking the question.  They only know if the answer "works" for them, for some arbitrary value of "works".  Or perhaps the answer just agrees with the asker's warped viewpoint.

Add to that the pressure to accept answers, and it's possible the answer was total garbage but was only accepted so someone would quit hounding them about accept rates.  Should someone get a badge because newbies were browbeaten into accepting sucky answers?  I think not.

Comment: Also, a lot of people tend to accept the answer which was only partially correct (or possibly incorrect) but led them to finding the correct answer, which really doesn't warrant any special treatment aside from the +15 reputation.