# Should accepted answers count as an upvote for tag totals?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should an accepted answer supply a “tag point”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46638/should-an-accepted-answer-supply-a-tag-point)

I get that if the user marks an answer correct, they "should" up-vote it, but why make that complex?  I see this all the time with new users.

Some argue that marking an answer correct has nothing to do with up-voting.  I disagree, receiving a random anonymous up-vote from someone shouldn't have more tag value than the OP's correctly marked answer.

**My suggestion:**

+15 for a correct answer, with 10 for the upvote and 5 for it being correct, and not allow any further upvoting by the OP(ie: +15, then +10 for one upvote).

Comment: What do you mean "not allow any further upvoting by the OP"? They can only upvote it once to begin with. You mean it should auto-upvote if the answer is accepted?

Comment: Yes, 10 of the 15 would be the upvote.

Comment: I see people voting, why not discuss your opinions?

Answer (score 2):

I think the current system is alright -- if a user find the answer in a poorly-written or poorly-explained answer, they can mark it "accepted", but if they wouldn't have upvoted the answer as a mildly-interested reader, they don't have to.

But if the answer is also *good* -- takes the time to explain things or give alternatives or is well-written -- then the questioner can *also* give the upvote.

Comment: I agree with you, but my concern is that people on SO usually have an area of expertise, tag counts and badges reflect that.  We are saying, yes you helped someone with exactly what they needed, yet it's not good enough to count for the tags.

Comment: That sounds great, but most askers don't seem to have any sense of such a distinction. That might be what *you'd* do, but I don't think it's what *most* people do.